How global variables are shared between packages (BPLs)?
Recently got to work with about 320000 lines of code that I must upgrade and convert to libraries. I created something like this:
BasicFunc.dpk      (define the singleton class + its class ctor)
  LibVclCode1_R.dpk  (initializes the singletons)
    LibVclCode1_D.dpk  (accesses the singletons)
      LibVclCode2_R.dpk 
        LibVclCode2_D.dpk  (accesses the singletons, contains the IDE expert)


Issue:
There are some global variables (singletons) that must be shared between packages.
TMySingleton<T: IInterface> = class

The singleton class has a class variable called
Lock: System.SysUtils.IReadWriteSync 

that is initialized in singleton's class constructor ( TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer ).
When I try to access the instance of the Singleton I get a crash because Lock = nil. I put a msg in the the class constructor, and I see the msg when I load the package into the IDE (right click on package, then "Install"). The crash appears later when I open a form that has components that access one of those singletons.
Even though there is little to no information about sharing global variables between packages in the official documentation, we have hints that "normal" global variables can be shared between BPLs... (for example the {$G+} help page implies this).
But this specific problem might thread-related (threads run in a different address space than the BPL?)

Note 1: I am not compiling with "Link with runtime packages"! We are not talking about this!
Note 2: The singleton with its locking mechanism was put in place because there were problem during program initialization, where the singleton was accessed (possibly) from multiple threads.
Now, this was fixed. But until I convince people to get rid of the Lock or even the singleton, I must make it work with packages.
_
There is very little documentation about this. If you know some resources, please share :)

You are saying you don't have "link with runtime packages" enabled. On the other hand you say that you see a message when the package is loaded into the IDE. These are mutually exclusive. Packages that are to be loaded into the IDE must be linked with runtime packages.

Hi. The design time packages are loaded into the IDE when you right click on them (in Project Manager) and choose "Install". In my case, the design time package (marked with _D in my post) requires the BasicFunc package, that calls the ShowMessage in the TMySingleton's class constructor.

"But this specific problem might thread-related (threads run in a different address space than the BPL?)" - a BPL is just a DLL with extra support for the RTL/VCL/FMX frameworks. It is loaded into the address space of the EXE that loads it. A thread has is own call stack, but otherwise runs in the same address space of the EXE.
